# Como fazer a inclusão de seletor next e prev sobre elementos XML

Tags: javascript, xml, dom

Estou tendo dificuldade em elipsar elementos XML sobre controle de fluxo *prev/next*, o que tenho é:

## Código

```js
function mostrar(i) {

var txt, parser, xmlDoc;
txt = "<carta>" +
   "<para>Marcos</para>" +
   "<de>Luciana</de>" +
   "<assunto>Pagamento</assunto>" +
   "<body>Quando foi efetuado o pagamento conosco?</body>" +
   "<para>Milena</para>" +
   "<de>Gustavo</de>" +
   "<assunto>Compra</assunto>" +
   "<body>Você acabou de adquirir um produto aqui!</body>" +
   "<para>Neiva</para>" +
   "<de>Lucas</de>" +
   "<assunto>Venda</assunto>" +
   "<body>Você tem experiencia com vendas diretas?</body>" +
   "</carta>";

parser = new DOMParser();
var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(txt,"text/xml");
el = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("carta");
document.getElementById("exibir").innerHTML =
    "Para: " +
    el[i].getElementsByTagName("para")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "<br>De: " +
    el[i].getElementsByTagName("de")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "<br>Mensagem: " + 
    el[i].getElementsByTagName("body")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
}

var i = 0;

mostrar(i);

function next() {
if (i < el.length - 1) {
    i++;
    mostrar(i);
}
}

function prev() {
   if (i > 0) {
   i--;
   mostrar(i);
   }
}
```

```html
<div id='exibir'> &nbsp; </div>

<hr size='1' color='silver' />

<input type="button" value="&#171 prev" onclick="prev()" />

<input type="button" value="next &#187 " onclick="next()" />
```

Preciso implementar no código acima, estes seletores JavaScript logo abaixo:

```
var i = 0;

mostrar(i);

function next() {
    if (i < el.length - 1) {
        i++;
        mostrar(i);
    }
}

function prev() {
   if (i > 0) {
       i--;
       mostrar(i);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segue a resposta:

```js
function mostrar() {

var txt, parser, xmlDoc;
txt = "<carta>" +
    "<item>" +
    "<para>Marcos</para>" +
    "<de>Luciana</de>" +
    "<assunto>Pagamento</assunto>" +
    "<body>Quando foi efetuado o pagamento conosco?</body>" +
    "</item>" +
    "<item>" +
    "<para>Milena</para>" +
    "<de>Gustavo</de>" +
    "<assunto>Compra</assunto>" +
    "<body>Você acabou de adquirir um produto aqui!</body>" +
    "</item>" +
    "<item>" +
    "<para>Neiva</para>" +
    "<de>Lucas</de>" +
    "<assunto>Venda</assunto>" +
    "<body>Você tem experiencia com vendas diretas?</body>" +
    "</item>" +
    "</carta>";

parser = new DOMParser();
var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(txt, "text/xml");
registro = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("carta")[0];
el = registro.getElementsByTagName("item");
document.getElementById("exibir").innerHTML =
    "Para: " +
    el[i].getElementsByTagName("para")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "<br>De: " +
    el[i].getElementsByTagName("de")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "<br>Mensagem: " +
    el[i].getElementsByTagName("body")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
}

var i = 0;

mostrar();

function next() {
    if (i < el.length - 1) {
        i++;
        mostrar();
    }
}

function prev() {
    if (i > 0) {
        i--;
        mostrar();
    }
}
```

```html
<div id='exibir'> &nbsp; </div>

<hr size='1' color='silver' />

<input type="button" value="&#171 prev" onclick="prev()" />

<input type="button" value="next &#187 " onclick="next()" />
```

## Confira agora as mudanças que se fez necessárias para obter o perfeito funcionamento

**Antes** `mostrar(i)`

**Depois** `mostrar()`

Não foi preciso argumenta `var i` sobre a função `mostrar`, sem efeito algum sobre a função.

**Antes** `xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("carta");`

**Depois** `xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("carta")[0];`

Foi de vital importância setar um índice de vetor `[0]`, veremos o do porque disso na seguinte explicação mais abaixo.

**Antes**

```
txt = "<carta>" +
    "<para>Marcos</para>" +
    "<de>Luciana</de>" +
    "<assunto>Pagamento</assunto>" +
    "<body>Quando foi efetuado o pagamento conosco?</body>" +
    "<para>Milena</para>" +
    "<de>Gustavo</de>" +
    "<assunto>Compra</assunto>" +
    "<body>Você acabou de adquirir um produto aqui!</body>" +
    "<para>Neiva</para>" +
    "<de>Lucas</de>" +
    "<assunto>Venda</assunto>" +
    "<body>Você tem experiencia com vendas diretas?</body>" +
    "</carta>";
```

**Depois**

```
txt = "<carta>" +
   "<item>" +
   "<para>Marcos</para>" +
   "<de>Luciana</de>" +
   "<assunto>Pagamento</assunto>" +
   "<body>Quando foi efetuado o pagamento conosco?</body>" +
   "</item>" +
   "<item>" +
   "<para>Milena</para>" +
   "<de>Gustavo</de>" +
   "<assunto>Compra</assunto>" +
   "<body>Você acabou de adquirir um produto aqui!</body>" +
   "</item>" +
   "<item>" +
   "<para>Neiva</para>" +
   "<de>Lucas</de>" +
   "<assunto>Venda</assunto>" +
   "<body>Você tem experiencia com vendas diretas?</body>" +
   "</item>" +
   "</carta>";
```

Observe que agora fora incluída uma nova tag no XML o `<item>`, foi preciso por para percorrermos apenas um certo grupo de item de cada vez, como estava antes não era possível.

**Antes**

`el = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("carta");`

**Depois**

`registro = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("carta")[0];`

`el = registro.getElementsByTagName("item");`

Note aqui que foi definida uma nova `var registro` para elemento `carta`, ficando a `var el`(emento) para a nova tag `item`

Pronto!!! Contudo isso foi realizado funcionamento com sucesso.